# NO error but not working while retrieving rows from mysql database through php

Tags: php, mysql

This is php code for retrieving query from mysql database. This has no error as far as I know. Unfortunately this is not working. I cannot find the mistake.

```
        <?php 

                    if(isset($_POST['submit']))    // submit is submit button name as POST method
                    {               
                        $username = $_POST['in'];
                        $Timein= date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$username)));  // converting into mysql datetime format
                        $username = $_POST['out'];
                        $Timeout = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$username)));



                        $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','dev','dev@123','Database') or die('Error while connecting Database'.mysql_connect_error); 

                        // connection to database

                    $q="select * from camera where NOT chkin  > '$Timein' AND NOT chkout < '$Timeout'";
                    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);                             

                    // query 
                    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ ?>

                        // printing a bootstrap grid 
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                            <div class="tm-tours-box-2">                        
                                <img src="img/index-0 <?php echo $data['id'];?>.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="tm-tours-box-2-info">
                                    <h3 class="margin-bottom-15"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></h3>
                                    <p>Rs <?php echo $data['price']; ?>/day</p> 
                                </div>                      
                                <a  class="tm-tours-box-2-link" onclick="POP()">Book Now</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    <?php                                       

                    }   
                     }
        ?>
```

Comment: have you checked what  `$r` returns.

Comment: yes @webpic I have checked it.

Comment: Make sure your all queries returning proper values.

Comment: Define "not working." Have you run the query manually? It depends totally on the values (which should be parameters, do not put data from the user to queries directly!)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  it is not creating any grid column as it is supposed to do. I hope you get it.

Comment: @Bam can you show what data you are getting in `$r`.